# SSSD LDAP Setup for HDP

Tags: unix, hortonworks-data-platform, sssd

I am setting up SSSD for one of the HDP setup.

While SSSD is trying to sync users and groups, I am getting the following error message

(Tue Aug 29 07:58:12 2017) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [sdap_save_user] (0x0020): User [ambari-qa] filtered out! (primary gid out of range)
(Tue Aug 29 07:58:12 2017) [sssd[be[LDAP]]] [sdap_save_user] (0x0020): Failed to save user [ambari-qa]

Any idea how to overcome this error primary gid out of range?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use min_id or max_id in your config? If yes, then you need to increase that range to include the primary GID of that user being cached.